# A bug with the Hats Beanie display

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

I recently noticed this bug while visiting a new site:

[image: Hats Bug]

Having the beanie overlapped like that is rather annoying to be honest. Not sure if it is a wrong `z-index` value or relative positioning issues.